# Openshift ews classpath app.prop

Tags: java, jboss, openshift

Has anyone have any experience with adding properties file to openshift jobssEWS application?

I have Cloned the default git repo for jbossEWS and in the main-application folder, I created two dirs 
dev
  log4j.prop
  app.prop <-- has local mysql url, I set it in eclipse/IJ classpath -- works
prod
  log4j.prop
  app.prop  <-- has $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL urls

how do I add "prop" folder to class path?

I know I can copy the app.prop/log4j.prop to webapps/WEB_INF dir, but the it will override my local env. as well.

so if anyone knows how to just append to class path with one of my folders .. or a better solution, pls. let me know.

I know I can do maven profiles, but I need a quick solution dont have time right now to take a detour to dig profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I figured it out myself, I am posting it in case someone runs it to same issue.
you need to put your properties files in "src/main/resources" folder

I tested and it works